# Ghostscript add white background image

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have a script which automatically adds a gutter to a PDF file. It adds gutter to left for ODD numbered pages and gutter to the right for EVEN numbered pages. It does this by moving the existing image over.

Here is the code for that:

```
'gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -o output.pdf \
    -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=513 \
    -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=738 -dFIXEDMEDIA -c \
    "<< /CurrPageNum 1 def /Install { /CurrPageNum CurrPageNum 1 add def CurrPageNum 2 mod 1 eq \
    {-4.5 0 translate} {4.5 0 translate} \
    ifelse } bind  >> setpagedevice" -f input_file.pdf
```

I've found that when I send this PDF file to the printer, the additional space is not "counting" so the file is now narrower now. I think this is because transparency doesn't count on the PDF, and so when sent to the printer the pages are seen as narrower.

Is it possible to add a white background to the pdf so it ISN'T seen as transparent? Or is there an alternative way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your assumption is flawed, your 'translate' has no transparency involvement at all, its shifting the content on the media (NB this is not an image, ie a bitmap, in general. Its more complex content). **All** the content is shifted, no matter whether it is transparent or not.

I'm afraid I can't follow what you mean about the printed page being 'narrower'. The Media request will be for a page 513x738 points, which is a really weird size; 7.125 by 10.25 inches. Unles that matches the page size of your printer, then its going to do 'something' with the result. Probably it will center it if the media is larger than the request, but if the media is smaller than requested, then it will either scale it down or crop it. Either will result in something different to what you expect.

Is there a reason you are changing the media size of the original PDF file ?

If the media request does match the printer then its still possible that there will be cropping or scaling going on, because the printable area may not be the same as hte size of the media. The paper handling of some printers means that they cannot print all the way to the edge of the media. In that case the printer may scale or crop the output again.

You can easily elimiate transparency as being the culprit by simply starting with a test file which does not contain any transparency. If you aren't certain then one solution owuld be to use a recent version of Ghostscript and use the pdfimage32 device. That will create a PDF file from the original PDF, but the output file will **only** contain a bitmap image, no transparency at all.

To help us consider the problem, it would be helpful to see the original PDF file, the PDF file you send to the printer, and a scan or photograph of the final printed page. It would also be useful to know the version of Ghostscript you are using, the make and model of the printer, and how you are sending the PDF file to the printer.

Comment: 7.125 by 10.25 inches is the correct dimensions I'm looking for to send to the printers. In this case, it's KDP Print.

Here's a link to an example page (the document is too large to link to):

https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5ce6cd1fc08a0f1dd105e77e/980x1400/96f88b68e635d9828387dac732d62508/image.png

I need to move the page over to the right in this instance, creating a "gutter" on the left.

Comment: I can create this gutter fine, but think the printers are not "seeing" this, and as a result they're reporting that the dimensions of the page is 7 by 10.25 inches

Comment: So, @KenS, my assumption is that the space is being seen as transparent and so not detected. So if I can create a background image BEHIND the page that is all white, then the printer will accept the file. Hope that makes sense

Comment: The 'gutter' you've added (by shifting the page content) isn't transparent, so I don't believe that can be causing a problem. The whole content is shifted by the amount **before** any marking operations take place. I'm not sure what the PNG you've linked to is, the output from the printer ? If so It doesn't really help, because I don't know what the original or the Ghostscript otuput looked like. If its hte original, then I don't know what the printed output looks like, nor the Ghostscript output (in fact if its a PNG it can't be the original)